# How to search google doc filetype from google?

Tags: google-docs, google-search

Is it possible to search for google docs documents/filetype from google search engine?

I know it's possible to search for `.doc` file types like so `trucks filetype:doc`

But is it possible to search for google doc filetype only?

Comment: Questions on **the use of third party web applications** are off-topic for [so]. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se]. I recommend reading their [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com//about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks. It's [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132643/how-to-search-google-doc-filetype-from-google) now. Should I delete the question here on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

*site:docs.google.com/document/d [search phrase]*

Example:

*site:docs.google.com/document/d volvo saab*

[image: Searching for Google Docs including key words volvo or saab]

Comment: Great idea to search by site. This achieves exactly what I was after